# ASP.NET adds extra closing tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.net render meta tag validly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224995/asp-net-render-meta-tag-validly)

This is in my .aspx file:

```
<meta name="viewport" runat="server" content="width=380,height=575" id="viewPort" />
```

This is what appears on the rendered HTML file in the browser:

```
<meta id="viewPort" name="viewport" content="width=380,height=575"></meta>
```

What actually appears is not HTML5-compliant.

Any idea why that is changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is obviously by design of ASP.NET:

**Workaround 1:**
Add the following code into your page_load event:

```
HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
keywords.Name = "keywords";
keywords.Content = "one two trhee;
Header.Controls.Add(keywords);
```

see: [ASP.net render meta tag validly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224995/asp-net-render-meta-tag-validly)

**Workaround 2:**

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (base.EnableLegacyRendering)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteBeginTag(this.TagName);
        this.RenderAttributes(writer);
        writer.Write(" />");
    }
}
```

see: [Asp.net closes meta tag incorrectly in html 4.01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298949/asp-net-closes-meta-tag-incorrectly-in-html-4-01)

Comment: Another workaround is to use a HtmlMeta control inside .aspx file like: <asp:HtmlMeta runat="server" ID="viewPort" name="viewport" content="width=380,height=575" />